# Blender 3.4 knife tool not working

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

The knife tool is not snapping to verticies when cutting, and also when I make cuts it will only make some cuts (see example). I dont have any duplicate faces or vertices, does anyone know whats causing this?

[image]

[image]

- these are two screenshots taken while trying to use the knife tool, as you can see the knife tool did not connect all the cuts.
  [image]
- knife tool NOT snapping to vert (the circle should be purple, not green).

Comment: It's snapping fine here. Can you share a simple Blend file that it's not working on? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @JohnEason heres a wetransfer link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/08e2e905b05ba01d1862874230ccb94e20221211005338/692c1dccf43156435db03b36fbc4aa9e20221211005414/60232a

Comment: Still working fine here with your blend file using Blender 3.4.

Comment: @JohnEason thats weird, i cant seem to get anything in the file to cut correctly..

Comment: Is it working ok with a new file and something like a subdivided UV sphere?

Comment: @JohnEason Im going to add a video to the orginal post, i tried adding a sphere and its doing  some very odd stuff ive never seen before. its like its cutting on the other side of the sphere, its very weird

Comment: @JohnEason heres a we transfer link, it wouldnt let me post the video   https://we.tl/t-w0qa7IQCl5

Comment: To be honest I've never seen anything like it and can't imagine what is causing it! Is it deleting those faces as well? Might be worth updating to Blender version 3.3.2 (You're using 3.3.1, not 3.4 as in the title) but I don't think there have been any bug fixes which would affect that.  Perhaps someone else here has an idea of what's going on.